# Get first item that meets a criteria or return first item

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I want to get the first item that meets a given criteria and if none of the items match that criteria, I just want to get the first item

This is what I currently do and what works, but I don't like it. Is there a more elegant way of doing the same in just one LINQ query?

```
LookupLine lookup;
Func<KeyValuePair<int,LookupLine>,bool> criteria = 
    (kv) => !kv.Value.Gruppe.StartsWith("SF");

if (lookupLines.Any(criteria))
{
    lookup = lookupLines.First(criteria).Value;
}
else if (lookupLines.Any())
{
    lookup = lookupLines.First().Value;
}

FirstRelevantGroup = lookup.Gruppe;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for a one-liner, you could do

```
lookupLines.OrderBy(kv => kv.Value.Gruppe.StartsWith("SF") ? 2 : 1).First();
```

But I think your solution better conveys your intentions, although it could be simplified to:

```
LookupLine lookup = lookupLines.FirstOrDefault(kv => !kv.Value.Gruppe.StartsWith("SF"));
if(lookup == null) {
   lookup = lookupLines.First();
}

FirstRelevantGroup = lookup.Value.Gruppe;
```

Now, you could turn the above into a coalesce, but again you'd be losing some readability:

```
FirstRelevantGroup = (
     lookupLines.FirstOrDefault(kv => !kv.Value.Gruppe.StartsWith("SF"))
     ?? lookupLines.First()
).Value.Gruppe;
```

Comment: KeyValuePair is a struct and can't be compared to null, but thanks, that gives me some confidence.

Comment: oops, yes, I missed that part. You can compare it to `default(KeyValuePair<int,LookupLine>)`, but I guess you can't coalesce it as in my last example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like an extension method.

```
public static T FirstIfNotFound<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,bool> predicate)
{
   if (source==null||predicate==null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
   return source.Any(predicate) ? source.FirstOrDefault(predicate) : source.First();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My favorite one liner for this is

```
source.Where(predicate).Concat(source).FirstOrDefault()
```

This returns

- The first matching element if there is one.
- The first element if note match.
- Null if the list is empty.